# jQuery this() selector doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: jquery, frontend

I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('.element').hover(
  function () {
      jQuery(this).find('div.thumbnail-meta-data-wrapper').show();
      jQuery(this).find('div.thumbnail-meta-data-wrapper').find('div.symbol').show();
  },
  function () {
      jQuery(this).find('.thumbnail-meta-data-wrapper').hide();
      jQuery(this).find('.thumbnail-meta-data-wrapper').find('.symbol').hide();
  }
);
```

and for some reason this works fine in Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox.
Where I'm making a mistake?

**EDIT:**
Live link: [konstrukt.rs/3dhouse/](http://konstrukt.rs/3dhouse/)

Comment: Do you see any error in console?

Comment: What html is this supposed to work with? what you've provided thus far should work in all browsers, assuming the html is valid resulting in all browsers getting the same dom structure.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle. You code seems fine.

Comment: @Sergio it enters hover function, the problem is somewhere in the selector

Comment: @dormitkon, I suggested because `hover` generates many events every time the mouse moves. `mouseenter` would generate just one.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or post a live link?

Comment: Live url: http://konstrukt.rs/3dhouse/

Comment: Your fiddle had a syntax error (missing `)`), but once I fixed that it behaves the same in FF as in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/PU7pV/1/

Comment: @nnnnnn, check his website. There there is a strange behavior. On the images under the slideshow. They get grey and a text comes above them.

Comment: I have fixed syntax in your fiddle and it's work now: http://jsfiddle.net/PU7pV/6/

Comment: @KevinB, yes, I know. It was a suggestion before knowing more about his problem. But I see his link now and the problem is there and not related to that. Thanks

Comment: I agree there is a strange behavior there and cannot find why... Can you try having `.symbol` with `display:block;` from the beginning and just hide/show `.thumbnail-meta-data-wrapper`, removing the jQuery line with the find().

Comment: I suggest you to delete this question and post it again, with focus not on jQuery but on CSS. And post the live link from beginning. Btw, are you loading jQuery UI twice in your page? check the .js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes I made that fixed text not appearing on hover in Firefox 22 on Mac Os X:

**.element:** removed css property `text-indent: -1e+8px;` (firefox marks the value of this property as incorrect)

**.thumbnail-meta-data-wrapper**: added css property `z-index:99;` (this element was below  the image with class `project-img project-img-visible` which has z-index of 1)